# Java and thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am creating a mutli threaded application, and I have a question regarding the use of synchronized methods.

Lets say I have the following component which would be accessed by multiple threads.

**Component.java**

```
public class Component {
    private boolean active;

    //Constructor
    public Component(){
        active = false;
    }

    synchronized public void initiate(){
        //do something
        active = true;
    }

    synchronized public void closedown(){
        //do something
        active = false;
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        //do something
    }

    public boolean isActive(){
        return active;
    }
}
```

If I have two threads accessing the the same Component object and the first thread gets halted in the `Component.closedown()` before it has set `active = false`, and the second thread picks up and calls `Component.isActive()`, will the second thread block until the first thread has finished the closedown, or will it get the returned value of true?

If it is the latter, how can I make this thread safe?

Comment: How are you "halting" the threads?

Comment: @AndyTurner what I mean halting is that if the JVM decides to pause the execution of the first thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the essence of mutual-exclusion locks (mutexes). If a thread gets descheduled by the OS while holding a mutex, all other threads requiring the mutex to proceed will be stalled.

The above is actually the reason why, even if we take care to make all our critical sections very short and fast to execute, mutexes will still cause occasional latency spikes, and the spikes will be huge in proportion to regular latency. For example, your simple getter will execute in a couple of nanoseconds when uncontended, but may take 10µs or more if the thread holding the mutex is descheduled at an inconvenient time.

NOTE: The code in your question lacks the `synchronized` designation on `isActive`, but I assume your question is about what would happen if it was synchronized—because the code has a data race without it. Specifically:

> will the second thread block until the first thread has finished the closedown, or will it get the returned value of true?

Without `synchronized` it will do neither: it won't block, but it won't be guaranteed to ever return the `true` value. You are only guaranteed to observe the initial value (that's what the data race is about).

If you are looking for a practical advice to improve your code, then don't synchronize `isActive` method, but make the `active` flag `volatile`. This is standard practice for your use case.

Comment: So if I changed `public boolean isActive()` to `synchronized public boolean isActive()` this would prevent `isActive` from returning while another thread is in a different synchronized method?

Comment: Exactly, that would be the essential feature of the `synchronized` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have use a `lock` to protect the critical sections. As some methods read from the value and some write to the value, you can try using a `ReadWriteLock`.

```
public class Component {
    private final ReentrantReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private boolean active;

    //Constructor
    public Component(){
        active = false;
    }

    public void initiate(){
        // non-critical section
        rwl.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            // critical section
            active = true;
        } finally {
            rwl.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public void closedown(){
        // non-critical section
        rwl.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            // critical section
            active = false;
        } finally {
            rwl.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        // do something
    }

    public boolean isActive(){
        rwl.readLock().lock();
        boolean status = active;
        rwl.readLock().unlock();
        return status;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a slow, lock-based reimplementation of the guarantees provided by a simple `volatile` variable.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Depends what is actually in the critical section. In this case, yes. If the critical section was more complex, then it is not the same.

Comment: Well yes, of course, if you write something else, then you have something else. OP's case is that he does something more in `initialize` and `closedown`, but not in `isActive`, so a RW Lock is not needed.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Imagine if somewhere there is `if (c.isActive()) { c.closedown(); }`. Without a RW Lock the body of `closedown()` could be executed multiple times instead of once.

Comment: _With or without_ the RW lock it may be executed several times. Plus, to fix it, you'll need to cover the whole conditional block with a plain lock.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It won't be executed additional times if one thread is already within the critical section of `closedown()` when the call to `isActive` is made. It will only be executed additional times if multiple threads call `isActive()` at once. Considering that `closedown()` will be much more complex and time consuming than `isActive()` it will vastly reduce (but not completely eliminate) the probability of multiple executions of `closedown()`.

Comment: I hope (for your own sake) you don't attribute any positive value to the "vast reduction of probability" because it actually worsens the problem by making it harder to reproduce.